# finding a given list from storage/bank of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

i am trying a little pep project on python 3.7 but cant seem to get this to work.  I want to find a given list that is stored in an object holding many lists. I'm sure my coding is way off as I am pretty much a novice at this!

```
my_choice = ["a", "b", "c"]
reciepe1 = [["a", "b", "c"], "d", "e", "f"]
reciepe2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
menu = [reciepe1, reciepe2]
for my_choice in menu:
    if my_choice in reciepe1:
        print(reciepe1)
    elif my_choice in reciepe2:
        print(reciepe2)
```

Comment: The iteration variable and choice variable are same.

Comment: @SinclairAkoto - Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was almost correct, you just messed up the variables and you don't actually need the `elif`:

```
my_choice = ["a", "b", "c"]
recipe1 = [["a", "b", "c"], "d", "e", "f"]
recipe2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
menu = [recipe1, recipe2]
for recipe in menu:
    if my_choice in recipe:
        print(recipe)
```

outputs

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Thanks now looking at at I can see where I went wrong lol as a novice I really appreciate the help !

Answer (score 0):

### One of the methods is to use a dictionary as follows:

```
#  possible successful my_choices are from --> ["a", "b", "c"], "d", "e", "f", "x", "y", "z",
#  In case your my_choice is --> "a", then you have to **flatten** the list of all reciepe's.
my_choice = ["a", "b", "c"]

#create a dictionary as follows:
reciepe_final = {"reciepe1": [["a", "b", "c"], "d", "e", "f"],
                "reciepe2" : ["x", "y", "z"]}

#loop through the key and values of each reciepe
for k, i in reciepe_final.items():
    #if my_choice found in values print the key (reciepe(n))
    if my_choice in i: print (k)

#result --> reciepe1
```

If you want to flatten the list then either search in stack overflow/google or let me know, I will provide you the code.

Comment: thank you so much, just by looking at this it makes all the sense - will try this and let you know !

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! I tried this and it worked! what I wanted was to be able to print the recipe and the contents of the recipe also so at the end I put print(k,i) and it worked like a dream!!

Comment: @SinclairAkoto: happy to help.. :)